# How to create access point programmatically

Tags: android

I've written the code to create an access point for android devices. I've tested on both emulator and real device.But it doesn't work. Where did i get wrong?

```
public class MainWAP extends Activity {

    WifiManager wifiManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wap);
    }

    public void openWifi(View v) {
        createWifiAccessPoint();
    }

    private void createWifiAccessPoint() {
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
        Method[] wmMethods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        boolean methodFound = false;
        for (Method method: wmMethods) {
            if (method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")) {
                methodFound = true;
                WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                netConfig.SSID = "AccessPoint";
                netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(
                    WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                try {
                    boolean apstatus = (Boolean) method.invoke(
                        wifiManager, netConfig, true);
                    for (Method isWifiApEnabledmethod: wmMethods) {
                        if (isWifiApEnabledmethod.getName().equals(
                                "isWifiApEnabled")) {
                            while (!(Boolean) isWifiApEnabledmethod.invoke(
                                    wifiManager)) {};
                            for (Method method1: wmMethods) {
                                if (method1.getName().equals(
                                        "getWifiApState")) {
                                    int apstate;
                                    apstate = (Integer) method1.invoke(
                                        wifiManager);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (apstatus) {
                        Log.d("Splash Activity",
                            "Access Point created");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Splash Activity",
                            "Access Point creation failed");
                    }

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        if (!methodFound) {
            Log.d("Splash Activity",
                "cannot configure an access point");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some sort of related error message? Log message?

Comment: so is it now solved @daniel?

Comment: if you haven't done yet. Please check this out hope it might help you out : http://omtlab.com/android-check-network-connection-available-using-wifi/ @daniel

Comment: How do you turn it off?

Answer (score 8):

Your `WiFiManager` is definately not initialized.

In your `onCreate` method add this:

```
wifiManager = (WiFiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Comment: @Tom this is an answer to his question. If he'll initialize WiFiManager (and now it's `null`) everything will work fine (I've just tested it).

Comment: You just stated a fact. I think you should explain how it relates to the specific question and what should be done to solve the problem. There's a reason your answer has been automatically classified as low-quality.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. The post you replied to has been generated automatically by the review system.

Comment: wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    // to prevent memory leak

Answer (score 3):

You need few things to make this code to work.

1) Init wifiManager `onCreate()` :

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WiFiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

2) You need to ask for this permissions in you `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
```

3) Your application need to be signed with system certificates.

Comment: What do you mean in step 3?

Comment: @FabricioPH He meant that it needs to be a system application, if you try to use `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` it tells you that only system apps can use that permission.

Answer (score 0):

With your method of exploiting undocumented APIs using reflection, things might not work well in all scenarios. 
Well, you can try adding these in your manifest file and give a try.

```
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS
```

Comment: I've added in manifest file: android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.hardware.wifi, android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS. But when i run in emulator and click on button, it pop-up force close.

Comment: In the log message it show: 1)caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 2)caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: 1) Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at line 27: 
 `createWifiAccessPoint();`
2) Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException at line 33: `if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())` @WilHall