# Creating WPA2 PSK Access Point in Android Programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to create Access Point in android programmatically with the following configurations.
`AccessPointName :SomeName`
`Security:WPA2 PSK`
`Password:SomeKey`

How can i do that? 
Regards

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Its only create the Open network. Have u got any solution?

Answer (score 18):

I had faced this problem once. In order to create a WPA2 PSK access point, you need to populate the WifiConfiguartion object with your WPA2 PSK parameters.  However I could not find a way to set `KeyManagement` as `WPA2_PSK`. There was only options for `WPA_PSK`, `IEEE8021X`, `WPA_EAP` and `NONE`. Then I read the android source code for [WifiConfiguration.java](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.java). I was able to find out that indeed there is option for `WPA2_PSK`, but it is hidden by `@hide`, but it is an `int` with value `4`. So what I did was to pass `4` in `wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);`. See code below.

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfiguration.SSID = "SomeName";
wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "SomeKey";
wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = false;
wifiConfiguration.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
```

And finally pass this `wifiConfiguration` using [accesspoint](https://github.com/mvdan/accesspoint) as follows

```
WifiApControl apControl = WifiApControl.getInstance(context);

apControl.setEnabled(wifiConfiguration, true);
```

or else you can use this `wifiConfiguration` with reflection techniques in java to activate the access point.

Comment: This will adopt for android 6 also?

Comment: @Yuvaraja I have tested it on a device with Android 6.0.1 and it worked flowless.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, I have implemented your logic in code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175056/how-to-create-custom-wpa-hotspot-with-ssid-and-password-in-android could u check what is the problem?

Comment: Added netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4); in the config

Comment: @Yuvaraja I just checked the source of WifiConfiguration class on Android 6.0.1 and WPA2_PSK is still has value 4. So it should work. Let me try again with the code you have done.

Comment: Have you tried in android 6? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem by passing 4 as KeyMangement solved my problem.

```
WifiConfiguration myConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        myConfig.SSID = ssid; // SSID name of netwok
        myConfig.preSharedKey = password; // password for network
        myConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4); // 4 is for KeyMgmt.WPA2_PSK which is not exposed by android KeyMgmt class
        myConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN); // Set Auth Algorithms to open
        try {
            Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            return (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, myConfig, true);  // setting and turing on android wifiap with new configrations
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Read more at [Link](http://solutionsbits.com/how-to-create-a-wpa2_psk-based-hotspot-from-android-app/)

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment: // 4 is for KeyMgmt.WPA2_PSK which is not exposed by android KeyMgmt class that was the missing piece I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SO Thread at [How to create access point programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926738/how-to-create-access-point-programmatically).

However, if you see the code in that link, it is using JAVA Reflection technique to access underlying Android framework API. 
This is perhaps an indication that there is no direct API to toggle or program these system settings.

Also, looking at API Summary of Settings.System class in Android docs (BTW it is "final" class which gives hint that not too many things will be editable), there is no evidence that Android offers any API for apps to toggle/program system settings.

I gave the reference to that link only to highlight the fact that, to tweak Android system settings Such as APN, there seems to be no public/direct API provided by Android Framework, mostly because of Security Reasons.

We had a requirement in our project where I needed to programatically toggle internet radio, and in another case, I needed to dismiss Telephony dialog.

There is no public API to do that and only way to obtain desired result is using Reflection technique which is neither recommended nor portable and should be avoided.

Comment: It's not creating WPA2 PSK. It's creating open

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766425/android-programmatically-turn-on-wifi-hotspot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accesspoint](https://github.com/mvdan/accesspoint):

```
WifiApControl apControl = WifiApControl.getInstance(context);

apControl.setEnabled(wifiConfiguration, true);
```

You just need to populate the [WifiConfiguartion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html) object with your WPA2 PSK parameters.