# How to create Custom WPA Hotspot with ssid and password in android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, hotspot

I am using the following code for creating the Wifi-hotspot configuration.
I am able to create the Hotspot configuration and able to  enable it. but i have give configuration for WPA-PSK, But it always taken as OPEN network.

```
public boolean setHotSpot(String SSID,String passWord){
Method[] mMethods = mWifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

    for(Method mMethod: mMethods){

        if(mMethod.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")) {
            WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
             netConfig.SSID = SSID ;
                netConfig.preSharedKey = passWord;
                netConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
                netConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
                netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
                netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
                netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

            try {              
                mMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, netConfig,true);
                mWifiManager.saveConfiguration();
                return true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                CommonUtil.log(TAG,"Exception : "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
return false;
```

}

After run this app the Hotspot got enabled. Please check the image below.

[image]

How to set the WPA_PSK wifi configuration in android app?

As per below answer i have modified the code below.

```
public boolean setHotSpot(String SSID, String passWord) {
    boolean apstatus;
    WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
    if (passWord == "") {
        netConfig.SSID = SSID;
        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
    } else {
        netConfig.SSID = SSID;
        netConfig.preSharedKey = passWord;
                /*netConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
                netConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
                netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(4);
                netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
                netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
                netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);*/
        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
    }

    try {
        Method setWifiApMethod = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        //setWifiApMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, previousConfigurations, false);
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        apstatus = (Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, netConfig, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        CommonUtil.log(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return apstatus;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
```

replace above OPEN to SHARED

```
netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
```

Comment: its not working. its showing the same output mentioned above. Have you checked it with Android 6

Answer (score 0):

sollution

```
/** 
 * Uppsala University 
 *  
 * Project CS course, Fall 2012 
 * 
 * Projekt DV/Project CS, is a course in which the students develop software for 
 * distributed systems. The aim of the course is to give insights into how a big 
 * project is run (from planning to realization), how to construct a complex  
 * distributed system and to give hands-on experience on modern construction  
 * principles and programming methods. 
 * 
 * All rights reserved. 
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2012 LISA team 
 */ 
package project.cs.lisa.networksettings; 

import java.util.List; 

import android.content.Context; 
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager; 
import android.util.Log; 

public class WifiHandler { 
    //constants 
    public static final int WEP = 1;
    public static final int WAP = 2;
    public static final int OPEN_NETWORK = 3;

    public static final String TAG = "LISA_Network";

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    WifiConfiguration wifiConf;             /* WifiConfiguration object */

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    WifiManager wifiMgr;                            /* WifiManager object */

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    WifiInfo wifiInfo;                              /* WifiInfo object */

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    List<ScanResult> wifiScan;              /* List of ScanResult objects */

    /** 
     * Constructor initializes WifiManager and WifiInfo. 
     * @param context 
     */ 
    public WifiHandler(Context context) {
        wifiMgr  = getWifiManager(context);     // gets wifiMgr in the current context 
        wifiInfo = getWifiInfo(context);            // gets wifiInfo in the current context
        wifiConf = getWifiConf(context);            // gets wifiConf in the current context
        wifiScan = getWifiInRange();                    // gets wifiScan in the current context
    } 

    /** 
     * Function checkWifiEnabled checks if the WiFi connection 
     * is enabled on the device.  
     * @param wifiMgr 
     * @return true  if the WiFi connection is enabled, 
     *               false if the WiFi connection is disabled 
     */ 
    public boolean checkWifiEnabled() { 
        // checks if WiFi is enabled 
        return (wifiMgr != null && wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled());
    } 

    /** 
     * Function enableWifi enables WiFi connection on the device. 
     * @param wifiMgr 
     * @return true  if the attempt to enable WiFi succeeded, 
     *               false if the attempt to enable WiFi failed.  
     */ 
    public boolean enableWifi() { 
        // enables WiFi connection 
        return wifiMgr.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } 

    /** 
     * Function disableWifi disables WiFi connection on the device. 
     * @param wifiMgr 
     * @return true  if WiFi connection was disabled, 
     *               false if attempt to disable WiFi failed. 
     */ 
    public boolean disableWifi() { 
        // disables WiFi connection 
        return wifiMgr.setWifiEnabled(false);
    } 

    /** 
     * Function getWifiManager gets the WiFiManager object from the device. 
     * @param context 
     * @return WifiManager object. Also sets the class variable 
     *               wifiMgr as the WifiManager object returned. 
     */ 
    public WifiManager getWifiManager(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiMgr = null;

        // gets WifiManager obj from the system 
        wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (wifiMgr == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "WIFI_SERVICE is the wrong service name.");
        } 

        return wifiMgr;
    } 

    /** 
     * Function getWifiInfo gets the current WiFi connection information in a 
     * WifiInfo object from the device. 
     * @param context 
     * @return wifiInfo created object or 
     *               null       if wifi is not enabled. 
     */ 
    public WifiInfo getWifiInfo(Context context) {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = null;

        // gets WiFi network info of the current connection 
        if (checkWifiEnabled()) { 
            wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();   
        } 

        if (wifiInfo == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "WifiInfo object is empty.");
        } 

        return wifiInfo;
    } 

    /** 
     * Function that returns a WifiConfiguration object from the WifiInfo 
     * object from the class. If wifiInfo exists, then we are able to retrieve 
     * information from the current connection  
     * @param context 
     * @return WifiConfiguration object created. 
     */ 
    public WifiConfiguration getWifiConf(Context context) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

        if (wifiInfo == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "WifiInfo object is empty");
            return null; 
        } 

        wifiConfiguration.SSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        wifiConfiguration.networkId = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();

        return wifiConfiguration;
    } 

    /** 
     * Creates a new WifiConfiguration object for wifiConf. 
     */ 
    public void clearWifiConfig() { 
        wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
    } 

    /** 
     * Function getWifiInRange returns all the WiFi networks that are 
     * accessible through the access point (device AP) found during the 
     * last scan. 
     * @param wifi 
     * @return List of ScanResult containing information on all WiFi networks 
     *               discovered in the range. 
     */ 
    public List<ScanResult> getWifiInRange() {
        // gets ~last~ list of WiFi networks accessible through the access point. 
        return (wifiScan = (List<ScanResult>) wifiMgr.getScanResults());
    } 

    /** 
     * Function that scans for wifi networks available in the devices range. 
     * @return true  if scan started 
     *               false if scan could not be started  
     */ 
    public boolean scanWifiInRange() { 
        if (!checkWifiEnabled()) { 
            return false; 
        } 

        if (!wifiMgr.startScan()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to scan wifi's in range.");
            return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to disconnect from the currently connected WiFi AP. 
     * @return true  if disconnection succeeded 
     *               false if disconnection failed 
     */ 
    public boolean disconnectFromWifi() { 
        return (wifiMgr.disconnect());
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to connect to a selected network 
     * @param networkSSID         network SSID name 
     * @param   networkPassword     network password 
     * @param networkId           network ID from WifiManager 
     * @param SecurityProtocol    network security protocol 
     * @return true  if connection to selected network succeeded 
     *               false if connection to selected network failed 
     */ 
    public boolean connectToSelectedNetwork(String networkSSID, String networkPassword) {
        int networkId;
        int SecurityProtocol = WEP;

        // Clear wifi configuration variable 
        clearWifiConfig(); 

        // Sets network SSID name on wifiConf  
        wifiConf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        Log.d(TAG, "SSID Received: " + wifiConf.SSID);
        switch(SecurityProtocol) {
            // WEP "security". 
            case WEP:
                wifiConf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPassword + "\""; 
                wifiConf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
                wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                break; 

                // WAP security. We have to set preSharedKey. 
            case WAP:
                wifiConf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPassword +"\"";
                break; 

                // Network without security. 
            case OPEN_NETWORK:
                wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                break; 
        } 

        // Add WiFi configuration to list of recognizable networks 
        if ((networkId = wifiMgr.addNetwork(wifiConf)) == -1) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to add network configuration!");
            return false; 
        } 

        // Disconnect from current WiFi connection 
        if (!disconnectFromWifi()) { 
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to disconnect from network!");
            return false; 
        } 

        // Enable network to be connected 
        if (!wifiMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true)) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to enable network!");
            return false; 
        } 

        // Connect to network 
        if (!wifiMgr.reconnect()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to connect!");
            return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The code is for connecting other Wifi network by program. My problem is creating wifi-hotspot configuration form app.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in my app. Please check my code below.

**First add below permissions to your manifest.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

**Then create below MyHotspotManager .java class**

```
public class MyHotspotManager {
    private WifiConfiguration wifiCon;
    private HotspotDetails hotspotDetails;
    private WifiManager mWifiManager;

    public MyHotspotManager(WifiManager wifiManager){
        this.mWifiManager = wifiManager;
    }

    public boolean setHotspot(HotspotDetails hotspotDetails) {
        this.hotspotDetails = hotspotDetails;
        boolean apstatus;
        wifiCon = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiCon.SSID = hotspotDetails.getSsid();
        wifiCon.preSharedKey = hotspotDetails.getPassword();
        wifiCon.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        wifiCon.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiCon.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wifiCon.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        try {
            Method setWifiApMethod = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            //setWifiApMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, previousConfigurations, false);
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
            apstatus = (Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiCon, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e);
            return false;
        }

        return apstatus;
    }

}
```

**After that you can call the setHotspot method anywhere in you activity like below. Here I had to check whether app has the ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS permission.**

```
public void OnButtonClick(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again after giving access to Change system settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 200);

            }else{
                createHotspot();
            }
        }

    }

    private void createHotspot(){
        HotspotDetails hotspotDetails = new HotspotDetails();
        hotspotDetails.setSsid("TestStackOverFlow");
        hotspotDetails.setPassword("654321");
        new MyHotspotManager((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                .setHotspot(hotspotDetails);
    }
```

**But if you want you can omit permission request part by changing your targetSdkVersion to 21 in build.gradle. Now you can call it like below**

```
    public void OnButtonClick(View view) {
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
//            if (!Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext())) {
//                Toast.makeText(this, "Please try again after giving access to Change system settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
//                startActivityForResult(intent, 200);
//
//            }else{
//            }
//        }

        createHotspot();
    }

    private void createHotspot(){
        HotspotDetails hotspotDetails = new HotspotDetails();
        hotspotDetails.setSsid("TestStackOverFlow");
        hotspotDetails.setPassword("654321");
        new MyHotspotManager((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                .setHotspot(hotspotDetails);
    }
```

**This my HotspotDetails.java class**

```
public class HotspotDetails {
    private String ssid;
    private String password;

    public String getSsid() {
        return ssid;
    }

    public void setSsid(String ssid) {
        this.ssid = ssid;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ssid + ":" + password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay,The same stuff i have implemented already. Its always creating the Open Network, The WPA configuration and password not set. i have tried your code also. No luck.

Comment: @Yuvaraja It is already working for me. This is the code that I am using in my project. It is working on Android M also. Can you show me the updated hotspot creating method?

Comment: Check the updated code in above. I have modified the logic as per your input. but still no luck.