# Is there an Interoperable WiFi Mobile Peer to Peer Solution

Tags: android, iphone, wifip2p

Is there an interoperable WiFi Mobile Peer to Peer solution?  Apple has Multipeer Connection.  Android and Windows has WiFi direct.  The two P2P methods are not interoperable.  In other words, An iPhone cannot connect to Android.  There appear to be some proprietary solutions that are interoperable.  However, I think they are using Bluetooth which is a lot more interoperable.  Anybody know of a WiFi P2P solution that connects an iPhone to an Android phone?

Comment: maybe turning the Android into an AccessPoint and than connecting the iOS to it via normal wifi? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653084/creating-wpa2-psk-access-point-in-android-programmatically ?

Comment: I will have to think a little bit about your suggestion.  If I turn the Android into an access point, don't I now have a client/server scenario?  In other words, the iPhone has to initiate all transactions.  I had earlier thought about turning one phone into a server running node.js and just handle as a client/server.  However, the client/server scenario I found was too awkward.